# Sync two MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, database-replication

Have two separate databases. The master that holds the user information(username, password, address etc.). The slave database only has one table where the user name and password. I would like to happen is then an new user on the master db i created that the username and password is also added to the slave db.

Comment: Have you tried replication the table using a master slave configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with either a [TRIGGER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) or [STORED PROCEDURE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines.html).

In your case i guess you could use something like this (not tested):

```
CREATE TRIGGER `user_update` AFTER INSERT ON `User` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `mydb`.`UserLogin` (`id`, `UserName`, `Pass`) 
    VALUES (new.UserId, new.UserName, new.Password);
END$$
```

Comment: I figger that. The problem was more the connection to the other Database.

Comment: why not have one database with 2 tables? if you want to have 1 website talk to the first and the other only to the second you can do this with giving them permissions on one table and denying them on the second (and vice versa).

Comment: Because the master database has over 25 tables and the slave is only used for login access. The slave is also going to be used be other projects.

Comment: But if it's two separate databases. Who the connection made?

Comment: are they two different database on two different machines?!

Comment: Yes and no. They are two different database but right now it's on the same machine. But i would bee nice if could be separated.

Comment: Well if you want to write to another machine from a trigger i think you are out of luck. if it's on the same machine (in the same mysql installation) you can use the trigger i made. The slave_database.user will target the user table in the other database.

Comment: Im trying to do how you set it. But i have an problem i cant see why.`BEGIN
CREATE TRIGGER user_update 
AFTER INSERT ON User
REFERENCING
    NEW ROW AS NewUser
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO mydb.UserLogin (id, UserName, Pass)
VALUES (NewUser.UserId, NewUser.UserName, NewUser.Password); 
END`

Comment: try this. the backtics are not mandatory but help in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

We face a similar situation. We use Percona Toolkit's [pt-table-sync](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-table-sync.html) tool. It's rather simple to use.